Numerical Integration not successful
For a semi-cubical parabola we have by successive Chain Rule differentiation w.r.t. $t$,
$$\mu=\frac{x^3}{y^2}=\frac{3x^2x'}{2yy'}=\frac{6xx'+3x^2x''}{2y'^2+2yy''}~$$
Odes are formed by latter two equations with compatible boundary conditions:
EDIT1:
$$ (\mu=1,x=1,y=1,x_i=\frac12, y_i^{'}=\frac{3}{4})$$
but integration does not go through. Please help.
{mu, xi, yi, xdi, ydi} = {1., 1, 1, 0.5, 3./16};
equn = {(2.*Y'[t]^2 + 2*Y[t]*Y''[t]) mu == 
    6. X[t]*X'[t] + 3 X[t]^2*X''[t], (2.*Y[t]*Y'[t]) mu == 
    3. X[t]^2*X'[t], X[0] == xi, Y[0] == yi, X'[0] == xdi, 
   Y'[0] == ydi};

NDSolve[equn, {X, Y}, {t, 0, 3}];
{x[u_], y[u_]} = {X[u], Y[u]};
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, .1, 3}]

ode /. t -> 0 /. Last@Solve[ics]
{1.` (1.125` + 2 (Y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]) == 
  3.` + 3 (X^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0], True}


If you check ode for t->0 you get ({(2.*Y'[t]^2 + 2*Y[t]*Y''[t]) mu ==       6. X[t]*X'[t] + 3 X[t]^2*X''[t], (2.*Y[t]*Y'[t]) mu ==       3. X[t]^2*X'[t]}) /. t -> 0 /. {X[0] -> xi, Y[0] -> yi,    X'[0] -> xdi, Y'[0] -> ydi}   (*{1. (0.0703125 + 2 (Y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]) ==    3. + 3 (X^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0], False}*) . Second ode doesn't give usable start value!

Clearly so. At the origin there is no continuity since it is a cusp there. That is why I took the IC away from $(x=0,y=0)$ avoiding potential singularity troubles. It should work up to the origin where it crashes.

I don't think ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, .1, 3}] will show a curve anymore than ParametricPlot[{foo[t], bar[t]}, {t, .1, 3}] will. Maybe the 2nd-to-last line does not do what you want. It's not clear what the plot is for anyway, since I think you're asking about NDSolve. But maybe I'm wrong, and you don't know why the plot is blank.

The ICs do not satisfy the needed equations, so it's not a consistent setup.

There is a lot of possible parametrizations of  a semi-cubical parabola as the result [{x(t) = 0}, {y(t) = 0}], [{x(t) = x(t)}, {y(t) = sqrt(mu*x(t))*x(t)/mu, y(t) = -sqrt(mu*x(t))*x(t)/mu}] of Maple 2024 command dsolve({diff(eval(mu*y^2 = x^3, {x = x(t), y = y(t)}), t), mu*y(t)^2 = x(t)^3}, {x(t), y(t)}) shows. For example, one may put x(t)=t + sin(t). Unfortunately, DSolve[{y[t]^2 == x[t]^3,    D[y^2 == x^3 /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t]}, t]}, {x[t], y[t]}, t] returns the input in 14.0 on Windows 10.
